# BackgroundMediaPlayer only plays sound while debugging

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

When my mobile app is suspended I want to play a sound every two seconds.

In `OnSuspending` I call `BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current` to initiate the background task.

AudioTask:

```
public sealed class AudioTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    private ThreadPoolTimer timer;
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral;
    private bool canceled;

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("AudioTask starting");
        deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        StorageFolder folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("sound.wav");
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.AutoPlay = false;
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SetStreamSource(stream);

        timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(new TimerElapsedHandler(PeriodicTimerCallback), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        taskInstance.Canceled += new BackgroundTaskCanceledEventHandler(OnCanceled);
    }

    private void OnCanceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("AudioTask canceled");
        canceled = true;
    }

    private void PeriodicTimerCallback(ThreadPoolTimer timer)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("AudioTask timer callback");
        if (!canceled)
        {
            BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Cancel();
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine while debugging, but when I use the app without the debugger no sound is being played.

Comment: When you debugging did you put your app in suspended state?

Comment: @LovetoCode yes, via the Debug Location toolbar I select suspend.

Comment: Is background task Windows Runtime component?

Comment: I guess it will take time to start the task. Just try starting background task before suspending event.

Comment: Have you already solved your problem? The app from running status to suspending status may need five seconds, does the backgroundmedia trigger after five seconds?